# If statement for next button in a bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I ran into a quick problem, I don't know what condition to give for the if in my page, which makes sure that modal content whilst clicking next goes from last to first when it reaches the end.

```js
$("#next-btn").on("click", function() {
  if (currentMarineKnotIndex - 1 == 0) {
    currentMarineKnotIndex = receivedArray.length - 1;
  } else {
    currentMarineKnotIndex++;
  }
  $("#marine-knot-div").html(receivedArray[currentMarineKnotIndex].nameLV + "<br>" + receivedArray[currentMarineKnotIndex].descriptionLV);
  $("#modal-header-div").css("background", "url('../Images/uploads/" + receivedArray[currentMarineKnotIndex].Image + "')");
});

$("#prev-btn").on("click", function() {
  if (currentMarineKnotIndex + 1 == 0) {
    currentMarineKnotIndex = receivedArray.length - 1;
  } else {
    currentMarineKnotIndex--;
  }
  $("#marine-knot-div").html(receivedArray[currentMarineKnotIndex].nameLV + "<br>" + receivedArray[currentMarineKnotIndex].descriptionLV);
  $("#modal-header-div").css("background", "url('../Images/uploads/" + receivedArray[currentMarineKnotIndex].Image + "')");
});
```

I made it work for the previous button, but I don't know what to do for next.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to change the condition..

```
$("#next-btn").on("click", function() {
            if(currentMarineKnotIndex-1 == receivedArray.length){
                    currentMarineKnotIndex = receivedArray.length -1;
                }
                else{
                    currentMarineKnotIndex++;
                }
            $("#marine-knot-div").html(receivedArray[currentMarineKnotIndex].nameLV+"<br>"+receivedArray[currentMarineKnotIndex].descriptionLV);
            $("#modal-header-div").css("background", "url('../Images/uploads/"+receivedArray[currentMarineKnotIndex].Image+"')");
        });
        $("#prev-btn").on("click", function() {
           if(currentMarineKnotIndex+1 == 0){
                currentMarineKnotIndex = receivedArray.length - 1;
            }else{
                currentMarineKnotIndex--;
            }
            $("#marine-knot-div").html(receivedArray[currentMarineKnotIndex].nameLV+"<br>"+receivedArray[currentMarineKnotIndex].descriptionLV);
            $("#modal-header-div").css("background", "url('../Images/uploads/"+receivedArray[currentMarineKnotIndex].Image+"')");
```

Comment: Please check again `currentMarineKnotIndex-1 == receivedArray.length` would imply that `currentMarineKnotIndex` is already `> receivedArray.length` and would have already given an error in the array access.

Answer (score 0):

Your next/previous seem to be going in the wrong direction, but essentially you have it.

One small change to check if you're at the end:

```
if (currentMarineKnotIndex + 1 == receivedArray.length) 
    currentMarineKnotIndex = 0; 
else 
    currentMarineKnotIndex++;
```

(or `if (currentMarineKnotIndex == receivedArray.length - 1)`)

and going the other way:

```
if (currentMarineKnotIndex == 0) {
```

these both assume a zero-based index, which matches the array access.

Updated code, including next/prev direction fix:

```js
$("#next-btn").on("click", function() {
  if (currentMarineKnotIndex == receivedArray.length - 1) {
    currentMarineKnotIndex = 0;
  } else {
    currentMarineKnotIndex++;
  }
  $("#marine-knot-div").html(receivedArray[currentMarineKnotIndex].nameLV + "<br>" + receivedArray[currentMarineKnotIndex].descriptionLV);
  $("#modal-header-div").css("background", "url('../Images/uploads/" + receivedArray[currentMarineKnotIndex].Image + "')");
});

$("#prev-btn").on("click", function() {
  if (currentMarineKnotIndex == 0) {
    currentMarineKnotIndex = receivedArray.length - 1;
  } else {
    currentMarineKnotIndex--;
  }
  $("#marine-knot-div").html(receivedArray[currentMarineKnotIndex].nameLV + "<br>" + receivedArray[currentMarineKnotIndex].descriptionLV);
  $("#modal-header-div").css("background", "url('../Images/uploads/" + receivedArray[currentMarineKnotIndex].Image + "')");
});
```

As a bonus, you could move the common code (the `.html` and `.css`) parts to a separate function so you don't have duplicated code, but that wasn't part of the question.